# Avoiding Circular Dependency

Tags: arithmetic, finance

I have a calculation to work out the monthly rental for a vehicle based on the amount borrowed from the lender, and the price of the car after a certain mileage and period.

I cant figure out to put all the logic into this question as its based in a spreadsheet, so I have posted it here....

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xm1tH0DHrBA06NZhcd2rFQ78IT4Q0Wjpr6ltYfYh4Gk/edit?usp=sharing

The problem is....

1. The **Total Rental** is currently edited manually up and down until the **Monthly Surplus** reaches £50.
2. What we want, is to get the **Total Rental** automatically, by manually editing the **Monthly Surplus** field. The problem with this, is that the **Total to Be Funded** is based on a subtraction of 3 times the **Monthly Rental**. And the total to be funded is needed to work out the **Monthly Rental**, so creating a circular dependency.

Can anyone figure out a way around this?

**Update:**

In a separate sheet (now editable by anyone), we have the monthly rental being automatically calculated (massive thanks to @tilper), but we find ourselves at another circular dependency once we need to take away the deposit from the total amount funded.

My client does not want to borrow the deposit from the lender if the customer is paying it upfront anyway. This means the client can borrow less from the lender, and pass the savings onto the customer.

The remaining issue is that in this sheet....

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xm1tH0DHrBA06NZhcd2rFQ78IT4Q0Wjpr6ltYfYh4Gk/edit#gid=982363413

**B7** needs to take away **D25** , but cant because the result in **D25** is calculated (way up the chain) from **B7**.

Comment: So you want everything to depend solely on the monthly surplus field?

Comment: Yes, my client wants to type in a monthly surplus, and be given a monthly rental price based on the other factors such as vehicle price and funding etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just reverse engineer it based on the formulas for the cells.

The formula for cell $B30$ (Monthly Surplus) is $B30 = B29/24$, where cell $B29$ is the Total Surplus.  This equation can be rewritten as $B29 = B30 \cdot 24$.  This tells us how to find the Total Surplus from the Monthly Surplus.

Note the current Total Surplus formula in cell $B29$.  It's $B29 = B28 - B27$.  Let's look at the formulas for cells $B27$ and $B28$.

- $B27$ (Total Contract Costs) $= B17 \cdot 29 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22$
- $B28$ (Total Contract Income) $= B25 \cdot 29$

Cell $B25$ is the Total Rental.  This is the one you want to generate automatically.  Yes, I see you also want to generate $D25$ automatically but that will happen once we get $B25$, because the formula for $D25$ already depends on $B25$.

Anyway, from the second bullet point above we get $B25 = B28 / 29$.  So this tells us how to find $B25$ using $B28$.  But how do we get $B28$?

Well, we know that $B29 = B28 - B27$.  Therefore, $B28 = B29 + B27$.

And that's it!

To summarize with step-by-step instructions:

1. Change the formula for cell $B29$ to $B30 \cdot 24$.
2. Change the formula for cell $B28$ to $B29 + B27$.
3. Change the formula for cell $B25$ to $B28/29$.
4. Handle the circular dependency, outlined below.

We now have a circular dependency with $B25$.  We can resolve this by changing the formula in $B7$.  Unravel it by following the formulas:

\begin{align}
  B7 &= B1 - B3 - B5 - \color{red}{B25} \cdot 6\\
  \color{red}{B25} &= \color{blue}{B28}/29\\
  \color{blue}{B28} &= B29 + \color{green}{B27}\\
  \color{green}{B27} &= \color{orange}{B17} \cdot 29 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22\\
  \color{orange}{B17} &= B13 + B15\\
    &= B11 / 0.03608 + B9/0.00514\\
    &= (B7 - B9) / 0.03608 + B9/0.00514
\end{align}

Here are the major equalities from the above unraveling:

\begin{align}
  B7 &= B1 - B3 - B5 - B25 \cdot 6\\
  B25 &= B28/29\\
  B28 &= B29 + B27\\
  B27 &= B17 \cdot 29 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22\\
  B17 &= (B7 - B9) / 0.03608 + B9/0.00514
\end{align}

Now just do a lot of messy back-substitution:
\begin{align}
  B17 &= (B7 - B9) / 0.03608 + B9/0.00514\\
  B27 &= \color{orange}{B17} \cdot 29 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22\\
    &= \color{orange}{\left((B7 - B9) / 0.03608 + B9/0.00514\right)} \cdot 29 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22\\
    &= 803.76940133 (B7 - B9) + 5642.0233463 B9 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22\\
    &= 803.76940133 B7 + 4838.25394497 B9 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22
\end{align}

That was one step of the back-substitution.  The next step is:
\begin{align}
  B27 &= 803.76940133 B7 + 4838.25394497 B9 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22\\
  B28 &= B29 + \color{green}{B27}\\
    &= B29 + \color{green}{803.76940133 B7 + 4838.25394497 B9 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22}\\
    &= B29 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22 + 803.76940133 B7 + 4838.25394497 B9\\
\end{align}

Luckily that wasn't as messy.  The rest aren't that bad also.  Next:
\begin{align}
  B28 &= B29 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22 + 803.76940133 B7 + 4838.25394497 B9\\
  B25 &= \color{blue}{B28}/29\\
    &= \color{blue}{(B29 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22 + 803.76940133 B7 + 4838.25394497 B9)}/29\\
    &= \frac{1}{29}(B29 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22) + 27.71618625 B7 + 166.83634293 B9
\end{align}

And finally:
\begin{align}
  B25 &= \frac{1}{29}(B29 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22) + 27.71618625 B7 + 166.83634293 B9\\
  B7 &= B1 - B3 - B5 - \color{red}{B25} \cdot 6\\
    &= B1 - B3 - B5 - \color{red}{\left[\frac{1}{29}(\cdots) + 27.71618625 B7 + 166.83634293 B9\right]} \cdot 6\\
    &= B1 - B3 - B5 - \frac{6}{29}(\cdots) + 27.71618625 B7 + 166.83634293 B9
\end{align}
I'm using the $\cdots$ in the parentheses above instead of fully writing out $B29 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22$ because otherwise the equations would wrap to the next line and be harder to read.  Anyway, now we have the following equation:
$$
 B7 = B1 - B3 - B5 - \frac{6}{29}(B29 + B19 + B20 + B21 + B22) + 27.71618625 B7 + 166.83634293 B9
$$

Solve this for $B7$ just like you'd solve any other linear equation in one variable.  Then you'll have a new formula you can put in cell $B7$ and it won't have circular dependencies.  I should point out that I haven't really verified that I didn't make any arithmetic mistakes.  There's a chance the numbers may be off, but this is the process you'll want to follow to remove the dependency.

---

A couple things I wanted to note:

- Some of the formulas can be cleaned up.  For example, $B7$ currently says `=SUM(B1-B3-B5-(B25*6))`.  The "SUM" here makes no sense.  It's better to just say `=B1-B3-B5-(B25*6)`.  Note that the parentheses around $B25*6$ are also not needed but aren't really harmful or a bad idea.
- The formula for cell $B34$ is `=B33/1.2*0.9`.  This gets interpreted as $\dfrac{B33}{1.2} \cdot 0.9$, and **not** $\dfrac{B33}{1.2 \cdot 0.9}$, because of order of operations.  Please verify this is the intended result.  I point this out only because I've seen this error more times than I can count.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I changed the first two, and tried changing B25 to B28/29 but we are met with the circular dependency again. The calculated value in B27 is based on a value already being present in B25

Comment: @Collins, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those notes, luckily that was the intended behaviour, but i have removed the SUM. No matter what I do, i still cant get this example to work. I'm not clued up on what α,β,γ is, and how to involve them in the sheet.  You say you tested it, are you able to edit that sheet and show me? I really really appreciate all of your time on this

Comment: @Collins I tested it without all of the formulas because I had to use an external spreadsheet to edit, and I missed a formula that contributed to the circular dependency.  Can check later but will be a while. Did you do the back subs?  Note that I simplified the answer a bit.  In that last chain of equations (before "now just do a lot of..." and after "here are the major equalities...") start at the bottom and substitute upwards. The last equation tells you how to express $B17$ in terms of $B7$ and $B9$.   Put that expression in the next equation up, simplify, repeat the process. (1/2)

Comment: @Collins Then once you've back subbed all the way up you'll get something in that general form (if I thought about it correctly).  The $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are the numbers that come from simplifying the expressions along the way. (2/2)

Comment: OK, I did everything you said, and it gets us a Total Rental of 198.63 , which is technically correct, but the Total to be funded does not need to include the upfront deposit paid by the customer. Once this is taken away, we are looking at a much cheaper monthly rental for the customer, while still preserving the margin... The issue is a circular dependency after taking D25 from B7

Comment: Please see updated question for current situation

Comment: @Collins But it looks like you haven't done everything I said.  The formula in $B7$ is still basically the same.  Instead of unraveling it looks like you went one step in the opposite direction.  Take the right-hand side (RHS) of the $B17$ equation, substitute it for $B17$ in the $B27$ equation, simplify.  Take the RHS of the new $B27$ equation, substitute it for $B27$ in the $B28$ equation, simplify.  Repeat this process until there are no more equations to substitute.  Then you'll have an equation that you can solve for $B7$ which will not have any circular dependencies.

Comment: @Collins I updated the answer with the back subs.

Comment: Thank you for all of your time on this. In the final equation, there is 27.71618625B7 , is that 27.71618625 * B7 ? Using the B7 again in the equation has caused another circular :-(

Comment: @Collins Yes, that's the right interpretation, but you still missed a step that I explained but didn't explicitly do:  "Solve this for $B7$ just like you'd solve any other linear equation in one variable."

Comment: @Collins did you get this worked out?

Comment: No I'm still struggling with it. I tried moving it all to PHP to try and use for statements to replicate the circular dependency, but Im not getting the results I want.

Comment: @Collins, in the very last equation I wrote in the answer (before the two notes), subtract $27.71618625 \cdot B7$ from both sides.  Then you have $B7$ by itself on one side, multiplied by a number.  Divide both sides by that number and you have $B7$ without a dependency.

Comment: Thank you for all of your time on this. We managed to achieve the final result. I have added bounty, and will award to you as well for your time and great answer.

Comment: @Collins Great, glad to hear it, thanks!